# Datatables - how to retain filter data and reassign them to dropdowns

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm using Jquery datatables and it has filters in the form of dropdowns. The HTML looks like below.

```
<table id="example">
   <thead>
     <tr>
       <th>Name</th>
       <th>Position</th>
       <th>Office</th>
       <th>Age</th>
       <th>Start date</th>
       <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td></td>
       <td><select><option>-Filter-</option></select></td>
       <td><select><option>-Filter-</option></select></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
     </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
     <tr>
       <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
       <td>System Architect</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>2011-04-25</td>
       <td>$320,800</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
       <td>System Architect</td>
       <td>Edinburgh</td>
       <td>61</td>
       <td>2011-04-25</td>
       <td>$320,800</td>
     </tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Filter dropdown can be in any column as this is used in many places with different datasets. Therefore, I've made it dynamic with the use of Datatable's provided method and managed to get as far as locating the `<td>` element with the filter dropdown.

```
var filterColumn = $("#example thead tr:eq(1) td:eq(" + i + ") select");
```

In the code snippet above, `i` being the column number which comes from the overarching function and successfully get assigned inside td:eq, however, my Jquery selector won't return the dropdown inside the table cell, instead returns Jquery Object as below.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated to fix the selector.

JS bin - https://jsbin.com/badopohino/edit?html,js,output

Thanks.

```js
$('#example').DataTable({
  orderCellsTop: true,
  stateSave: true,
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api()
      .columns([1, 2])
      .every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select class="form-control form-control--filter"><option value=""> -- Filter -- </option></select>')
          .appendTo($('thead tr:eq(1) td:eq(' + this.index() + ')'))
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );
            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          if (!d == '') {
            select.append('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
          }
        });
      });
  },
  stateLoadParams: function(settings, data) {
    for (i = 0; i < data.columns["length"]; i++) {
      var col_search_val = data.columns[i].search.search;

      if (col_search_val != "") {
        var filterColumn = $("#example thead tr:eq(1) td:eq(" + i + ") select");
        console.log(filterColumn, i);
      }
    }
  }


});

var abc = $("#example thead tr:eq(1) td:eq(1) select");

//console.log(abc);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011-04-25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011-07-25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009-01-12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012-03-29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008-11-28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012-12-02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  </body>

  </html>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar - https://jsbin.com/badopohino/edit?html,js,output
Thanks

Comment: Post it HERE, not at an external site. That's why we have Stack Snippet.

Comment: I added your code to the playcode.io , instead of `i` i used number 1 or 2, and it works ok https://playcode.io/974741 I believe your `i` variable wrong

Comment: `$(...)` always returns a jQuery object. You can use `.get(0)` to get the underlying DOM element. But it says that the length is 0, so it's not matching anything.

Comment: Just added the code snippet here @Barmar

Comment: @KonstantinSavusia yes, I tried that approach too. But my i variable returns the correct column number which is why I'm baffled as to what's wrong. thanks.

Comment: What do we have to do to trigger the console log?

Comment: If you want an ordinary DOM element use `document.querySelector()` instead of `$()`

Comment: @Barmar - not sure why the console.log not working inside the snippet but it works on page load within JSBin. The filters are parameterised and used across various tables with varying degree of datasets hence the dynamic column selection with i.

Comment: Did you notice any issues with my jquery selector?

Comment: I don't see anything at jsbin either.

Comment: Thats's very strange. https://jsbin.com/badopohino/edit?html,js,console,output

I can see both the i value with filterColumn variable contents. Please can you try clickin run with js button on top right corner of JSBIN, which should refresh? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, @Barmar, You'll have to select something from the filter and then reload the page for it to write to the console. I've had it selected and state was saved which is why I could see the console with output.

Comment: The `stateLoadParams` function runs before the filter controls are added to the DOM. That's why the selector isn't finding anything. If you set a breakpoint inside the function, you'll see that the controls aren't in the output window.

Comment: That's very helpful @Barmar. Any pointers on how to run the stateLoadParams after filter controls have been added to the DOM?

Comment: I don't know anything about Datatables, but I doubt you can. There's probably some other hook you can use that runs after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this by saving the filter data within the `stateLoadParms` method and then looping through them in the `initComplete` method and setting the selected value to the dropdown. Haven't tested the code below but what I was missing was that the Jquery selector couldn't find the dropdown elements inside table cells as they are added to the DOM later, as pointed out above by @Barmar.

```js
var filterData = [];
$('#example').DataTable({
  orderCellsTop: true,
  stateSave: true,
  initComplete: function() {
    this.api()
      .columns([1, 2])
      .every(function(index) {
        var column = this;
        var select = $('<select class="form-control form-control--filter"><option value=""> -- Filter -- </option></select>')
          .appendTo($('thead tr:eq(1) td:eq(' + this.index() + ')'))
          .on('change', function() {
            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
              $(this).val()
            );
            column
              .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();
          });

        var option;
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {
          if (!d == '') {
            option = $('<option value="' + d + '">' + d + '</option>');
            if (d == filterData[index]) {
              option.prop('selected', true);
            }
            select.append(option);
          }
        });

      });
  },
  stateLoadParams: function(settings, data) {
    data.columns.forEach(function(col, i) {
      filterData.push(col.search.search);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <title>JS Bin</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Position</th>
          <th>Office</th>
          <th>Age</th>
          <th>Start date</th>
          <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
          <td>System Architect</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2011-04-25</td>
          <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Garrett Winters</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>63</td>
          <td>2011-07-25</td>
          <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Ashton Cox</td>
          <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
          <td>San Francisco</td>
          <td>66</td>
          <td>2009-01-12</td>
          <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
          <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
          <td>Edinburgh</td>
          <td>22</td>
          <td>2012-03-29</td>
          <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Airi Satou</td>
          <td>Accountant</td>
          <td>Tokyo</td>
          <td>33</td>
          <td>2008-11-28</td>
          <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
          <td>Integration Specialist</td>
          <td>New York</td>
          <td>61</td>
          <td>2012-12-02</td>
          <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

  </body>

  </html>
</body>

</html>
```